# liftScreen validate custom fields

Tags: scala, lift

I am following the example which is given in the [lift wiki](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Add_custom_field_types_to_LiftScreen). I wonder how to give the validations like `valMinLen(length,msg)` when we creating a custom field. I tried various ways but hadn'thad any luck.

Please give an example of giving validations to a custom created field.

*edit* -

sorry if above question is not clear, this is the example in the assembla site,

```
object MyScreen extends LiftScreen { 
  val password = new Field { 
    type ValueType = String 
    override def name = "Password" 
    override implicit def manifest = buildIt[String] 
    override def default = "" 
    override def toForm: Box[NodeSeq] = SHtml.password(is, set _) 
  } 
}
```

In here I need to add a `valMinLen` validation, or I need to access the generated error string to replace it with my one. Is it possible

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your question or provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Using LiftScreen field or text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008793/using-liftscreen-field-or-text), there is more than one way to create a custom field.

If you use the makeField method in LiftScreen, you could say something like:

```
makeField[String](
      title,
      "",//"No phone number entered",
      field => SHtml.text("", (_:String)=>{registerThisSnippet()}, ("class","phone")),
      valMinLen(length,msg)
)
```

If you want to use the more verbose but thorough explicit object creation as in your posted example, you need to examine where in the Field class the property for validations lies.

```
object MyScreen extends LiftScreen { 
  val password = new Field { 
    type ValueType = String 
    override def name = "Password" 
    override implicit def manifest = buildIt[String] 
    override def default = "" 
    override def toForm: Box[NodeSeq] = SHtml.password(is, set _) 
    override def validations = valMinLen(length,msg) _ :: super.validations
  } 
}
```

For a very complete example, check out the excellent [Lift Cookbook recipe for validations](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/Adding+validation+to+a+field.html).